# Google Developer Tools: How can I filter by request method (e.g. POST) in the network tab?

Tags: http, filter, http-post, httprequest, google-chrome-devtools

How can I filter by request method (e.g. POST) in the network tab?

Putting "post" into the filter field does not help, because it filters only by files. Is there a speacial filter method for HTTP-Requests? E.g.: "Show me only POST requests?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The filter text field also supports various keywords that let you sort resources by various properties, such as file size using the larger-than keyword.

"method:POST|GET|PUT" - Show resources that were retrieved over a specified HTTP method type. DevTools populates the dropdown with all of the HTTP methods it has encountered.

[documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/resource-loading#filter-requests)

Comment: great, thank you very much! Is there a list of all available filter properties? Once given, you cannot delete the filter, is this a bug?

Comment: Yes, there is all available filters. 
I can rewrite and delete filter.

Comment: on os X you can command-space in filters for a dropdown of filter options like method (and for those options' values)